# Putting 2 divs on the same line

Tags: html, css

Update:I got the answer...thanks a lot Brad(in comments)

Update 2:i dont know how to give the best answer in comments

Update 3:I am giving best answer to  Michael as Sir brad has not given answer is answer section

i am trying hard to have 2 divs on the same line,but in vain

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgADB/)

```
 <br /><div id='topdiv1'><div id='topdiv3'><div id='div23 '>
<img src="http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png" /></div><span class="tab"></span>
 <img src='http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png'/></div></div>



span.tab{
padding: 0 50px; /* Or desired space*/
}
.div23 
{
display: inline
    float:left;
  }
   .span.tab 
{  
   display: inline
    float:left;
}
   .topdiv1 
  {
   display: inline
float:left;
  }
.topdiv3
  {
        display: inline
          float:left;
   }
```

i cant figure out where i am going wrong.plz help

Comment: First of all you have syntax errors.  Three times you missed the semi colon on display:inline.  (Should be display: inline; )

In addition to that you have further syntax errors where you are using ID's in HTML but you are referencing classes in your CSS.

Comment: Secondly, you have div ids of `div#` yet your styles are referencing classes of `.div#` (how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LgADB/2/)?)

Comment: thanks a ton sir!!

by the way.....
isnt is "." used for "id"
and # used for "class"

Comment: No, you have it exact opposite, which is why your code isn't working.  You also have errors in the way you have your div's layed out, please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors.

In HTML you have  and in CSS you are refencing x with a .

The . character refers to a class, not an ID.  To reference an ID you need to use #.  Or you can switch id="x" to class="x" and leave the css alone.

You also have your div structures nested improperly.  The following code solves your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/LgADB/4/

```
<div id='topdiv1'>

<div id='topdiv3'>
    <img src='http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png'/>
</div><!-- end topdiv3 -->

<div id='div23 '>
    <img src="http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png" />
</div><!-- end div23 -->

<span class="tab"></span>
</div><!-- end topdiv1 -->

span.tab{
    padding: 0 50px; /* Or desired space*/
}

#topdiv3 {
    float: left;
}

#div23 {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: He specified that he needs to have the divs nested as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="display:inline-block; margin-right:50px"><img src="http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png" /></div>
<div style="display:inline-block;"><img src='http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png'/></div>
```

or

```
<div style="float:left; margin-right:50px"><img src="http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png" /></div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src='http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png'/></div>
```

Comment: Actually i need a div wrapped because .i am creating a responsive design and i need to hide the 1st div when the screen width is smaller.....thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: hey,i got the ans..thanks a lot anywyas
http://jsfiddle.net/LgADB/2/

Answer (score 1):

have you try by setting width
like

```
<div>

<div style="float:left;width:10%"><img src='http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png'/></div>
<div style="float:left;width:10%"><img src='http://i.udm4.com/mac/48/163/163483.png'/></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result with much less CSS. [This will do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/LgADB/3/), although it might not be the solution you're looking for.

```
img {
    margin-right:50px;
    float:left;
}
```

EDIT: Of course, you'll want to make the `img` selector more specific; otherwise, you'll set all `<img/>` elements on the page.

Comment: He already has float:left there.  His problem is not the rules themselves so much as it is he has syntax errors everywhere.

Comment: I know that. I'm simply pointing out an alternate solution that uses much less CSS. Sometimes what is helpful in order to solve a problem is to realize that there may be more elegant solutions. He asks for 2 divs on one line. Of course, it looks like he means two imgs on one line, given his code.